# SQL - Latest date based on action

Tags: sql-server

I have several rows in a single table as follows:

`[id], [date1], [action1], [date2], [action2], [date3], [action3], [date4], [action4]`

and for each row want to return the latest date when the action (which is defined by a single letter) matches the desired code.

I suspect I will need to use the MAX() function somewhere, but not sure how to start?

Comment: Your table design is bad. Can you change it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Each action refers to a unique row and may occur at different dates. I want to isolate particular actions and bring through the most recent date it occurred on

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

(You can put your date columns instead of my variables.)

```
DECLARE @Date1 AS DATE
DECLARE @Date2 AS DATE
DECLARE @Date3 AS Date

SET @Date1 = GETDATE()
SET @Date2 = GETDATE() + 4
SET @Date3 = GETDATE() -4

SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN 
(CASE WHEN @Date1 > @Date2 THEN @Date1 ELSE @Date2 END) > @Date3 THEN
(CASE WHEN @Date1 > @Date2 THEN @Date1 ELSE @Date2 END) ELSE @Date3 END AS   result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` in combination with Common Table Expressions. Let's assume your table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
   ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   Date1 date NOT NULL,
   Action1 char(1) NOT NULL,
   Date2 date NOT NULL,
   Action2 char(1) NOT NULL,
   Date3 date NOT NULL,
   Action3 char(1) NOT NULL,
   Date4 date NOT NULL,
   Action4 char(1) NOT NULL
);
```

And some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(Date1, Action1, Date2, Action2, Date3, Action3, Date4, Action4)
   VALUES
      ('20170101', 'A', '20170201', 'A', '20170201', 'B', '20170101', 'C'),
      ('20170103', 'A', '20170203', 'B', '20170205', 'A', '20170101', 'C');
```

You can then `UNPIVOT` for actions and then for dates and then join these unpivoted results like so:

```
WITH Actions AS
   (
      SELECT ID, [Action]
         FROM
            (
               SELECT ID, Action1, Action2, Action3, Action4
                  FROM MyTable
            ) P
         UNPIVOT
            (
               [Action] FOR Col IN([Action1], [Action2], [Action3], [Action4])
            ) U
   ),
Dates AS   
   (
      SELECT ID, [Date]
         FROM
            (
               SELECT ID, Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4
                  FROM MyTable
            ) P
         UNPIVOT
            (
               [Date] FOR Col IN([Date1], [Date2], [Date3], [Date4])
            ) U
   )
SELECT
      A.ID, MAX(D.[Date]) AS MaxDate
   FROM
      Actions A
      INNER JOIN Dates D ON D.ID = A.ID
   WHERE
      A.Action = 'A'
   GROUP BY
      A.ID;
```

The result from this is

```
ID          MaxDate
----------- ----------
1           2017-02-01
2           2017-02-05
```